# Display Nos of Checked item, Javascript Multiple Select

Tags: javascript, multi-select, contact-form-7

I have a wp-cf7 based enquiry form, where a select box, display no of checkbox, i want to show the numbers of selected item.

please have look at [here](https://www.bestgoadeals.com/) how they used
**here is my code**

```
 <div style="position:relative" class="block">
<input type="button" value="Select Services" id="toggle1"><p></p>
<ul class="toggle1" style="display: none;">
<li><label><input type="checkbox" name="Booking[]" value="Hotels / Resort Booking">&nbsp;Hotels  </label></li>
<li><label><input type="checkbox" name="Packages[]" value="Holiday Packages">&nbsp;Packages</label></li> 
</ul></div>
```

Here is the code i already updated in [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/kb4rq36L/9/)  also

thanks and appreciate your suggestions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just need this code:

```
$('input').on('click', function(){
    alert($('input:checked').length);
});
```

You can create a div with a class and update it too. Here is an update of your example:

http://jsfiddle.net/8Lw4uvq3/1/

Also you should improve the indentation of your code.. its horrible to read.

Comment: thanks for reply, it working, is it possible if we can replace nos to  select services text ?